# recaptcha for Voting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have implemented an Ajax based voting system.As of now, my view is:

```
<%=button_to 'Vote',vote_path(:format=>:js,:id=>c.id),:remote=>true%>
```

and my controller is:

```
def vote
        @video=Video.find(params[:id])
        @video.increment!(:votes)

          respond_to do|format|
          format.js  
          end

     end
```

This mechanism works fine.But, i want to add reCaptcha to the voting system.I have all the necessary configurations in place.However, I'm confused as to what shud be the view and controller modifications for recaptcha. Thanks.

**Edit:** I'm using Ambesthia recaptcha

**Edit 2:** I would like to add the reCaptcha form more than once in the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the view inside your form, you need

```
<%= recaptcha_tags %>
```

to display the reCaptcha box in your page. Then in your controller method, which is handling the POST params, you can use the **verify_recaptcha** method.

Comment: Problem is not in showing Recaptcha, but in showing it more than once.

Comment: If that is the case, I don't think it is possible. You can use only one reCaptcha per page, so it should be shared for all forms. You may want to look for another captcha library, but I'm not aware of one which does what you need. I guess you can try creating the html for the recaptcha dynamically when user hovers over a form with the mouse, and then destroy the html if he hovers over another form and insert it there.

Comment: I did have a complicated work around for it.But [link](http://recaptcha.net/fastcgi/demo/ajax) This Sums it up pretty well